# unlimited number of values gets really big

Tags: nodes, entities, paging

I have created a content type with a field inside which can take unlimited number of values. eg a city with the names of its inhabitants.

The problem is that this number can get really big (i.e. 100000).

Up to 5000 people I can edit this node with no problems (apart from the fact that it takes much time to load). But above this number I just get a white screen.

What should I do in order to be able to edit (e.g. the name of a certain inhabitant) with no problems?

My UI idea would be something like pagination (loading 100 records each time I change the page), but is this possible?

Comment: What's the field type? Entity reference? You should be able to configure it to use autocomplete.

Comment: field type is text

Comment: As per @j-reynold's answer below, you should definitely have the inhabitant and city as separate entities. A multi-valued field attached to the node will lead to all sorts of problems, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 3):

Put the relationship the other way round, ie let every inhabitant be a separate entity that has an entity reference to a city.

Then you can still display them on a city content view by using an embedded view, such as [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) or [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) dynamic field, or using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). You can even embed it via a preprocess_node function using view_embed_view, and have pagination on it.

And views will use the inverse relationship just fine.

Look at the wiki entry for [Cardinality (data modeling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)) for more information on this principle.